# SQL, search keyword order by relevance

Tags: php, sql

So i have this query in my code for search a keyword in database :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE
(CONCAT(firstname,' ',name) LIKE :searchword OR
CONCAT(name,' ',firstname) LIKE :searchword)
```

So, i search :searchword in two fields : `firstname` and `name`.

How can i order the result of this query by relevance ?

For example, if i search "man" i want to retrieve names begins by "ma" and firstname begin by "ma"

Comment: how do you determine relevance? what's your logic?

Comment: Your example would not pass the `where` criteria.  Is that a valid example?  This isn't just an `order by` question.

Comment: it's a valid example...*

Comment: ..but the example does not explain what determines "relevance". (I believe the goal is to prioritize partially matching last names; be *clear* and *explicit* - showing example output is often helpful.)